# Finding overlapping intervals

Tags: r, dataframe, overlap

I have intervals in a data frame df like follows:

```
df=data.frame(Id=rep("A1",23),start=c(11176,11176,11176,11176,11176,11176,11176,11177,11177,11177,11177,11177,11177,11178,11178,11179,11179,11179,11233,11233,11233,11233,11233),end=c(11205,11206,11206,11206,11206,11206,11207,11206,11206,11208,11206,11208,11209,11206,11206,11203,11204,11204,11263,11263,11263,11263,11264))
```

Also I have query position as "`11180`". Now I would like get the overlapping intervals starting from intervals in which `11180` is part of it. I mean my query position(`11180`) lies between the first interval in df "`11176`" and `111205`. So I take this interval (`11176 and 111205`) and find intervals that overlap `11176` and `111205`. Later the intervals that overlap the overlapping intervals of `11176 and 111205` and so on until there is no overlap found and return that interval. I expect my code it to give `11179` and `11204` as last overlapping interval but somehow it reports only `11178` and `11206`. Below is my code

```
    for(i in 1:dim(df)[1])
{
  final_start=temp_start
  final_end=temp_end
 if((findInterval(final_end,c(df$start[i],df$end[i]),rightmost.closed = T,left.open = T)==1L) || (findInterval(final_start,c(df$start[i],df$end[i]),rightmost.closed = T,left.open = T)==1L))
   {
    final_start=df$start[i]
    final_end=df$end[i]
    print(final_start)
    print(final_end)
   } 
}
```

the above code takes the query range as input and stores the start and end in temp_start and temp_end. Later it checks the whether the temp_end or temp_start is within the range of the intervals in data frame `df` Any guidance would be very useful to me. Thanks in advance. Let me know if you need any more details.

Comment: Are you trying to find all intervals of "df" that overlap with 11180? Try looking at "IRanges" package -- e.g. look at the `subjectHits` of `findOverlaps(IRanges(11180, 11180), IRanges(df$start, df$end))` which contains the rows of intervals that overlap with 11180.

Comment: another very good overlap-function comes with `data.table`, called `foverlaps()`. Check out [this link](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/functions/foverlaps) for some great examples to wrap your head around the concept.

Comment: @alexis_laz I am trying to look the intervals that overlap 11180 and sub-sequentially the other intervals that overlap 11180's intervals and so on until there is no overlaps reported. But my code was able to cover only th half the distance.

Comment: @Carol : I guess, using package "IRanges", something like `df[subjectHits(findOverlaps(IRanges(11180, 11180), IRanges(df$start, df$end))), ]` seems to fit your description? You might, also, find `reduce` (from the same package) helpful.